# Admobs Interstitial ads example throws compilation error in iOS

Tags: ios, admob

Admobs Interstitial ads example throws error at the time of compilation.

Any help on fixing this issue, please share?

**Error:**

[image]

**Added Frameworks:**[image]

**Update:**

I added AudioToolBox.Frameworks, the number of errors reduced to 1 from 4. Below is the screen shot image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Below are the things I tried,

- Changed `GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.6.1` to `GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.7.0`
- Added `AVFoundation.framework`
- Added `CoreAudio.framework`

Answer (score 0):

You had missed `AudioToolBox.Frameworks`. Just import `AudioToolBox.Frameworks` to your project files.

Comment: I have added AudioToolBox and CoreAudio frameworks already. Still the problem is ON.

Comment: I think you are using google example project file. Did you add this to those project file? Are you import this one in your .m file?

Comment: Yes I have added... I've updated the question content with the list of frameworks added. Please check once.

Comment: Did you try this with device?

Comment: Here is the sample application: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios

Comment: Ya I'm checking. I'm also getting same error. If I have found source of issue. I'll inform to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43394/discussion-between-thatzprem-and-mani)